# Restrict Direct IP Access To Website Without Affecting Other Sites

Tags: apache-2.2, apache2

I have several sites hosted on my server. If you directly type in the IP address to the server it will take you to one of the sites, I wanted to restrict this behaviour so I used the following fix:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
   ServerName 192.168.1.1
   Redirect 403 /
   ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ServerAdmin support@siteadmin.com
   UseCanonicalName Off
   #UserDir disabled
</VirtualHost>
```

And it worked for restricting direct IP access, however now my other sites are now unreachable and display the forbidden message.

How can I change this so that direct IP access is still forbidden, but my other sites are still able to be reached using their Domain Names?

Here is my full config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://admin.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
   ServerName 192.168.1.1
   Redirect 403 /
   ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ServerAdmin support@example.com
   UseCanonicalName Off
   #UserDir disabled
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName admin.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/user/example/static
        <Directory /home/user/example/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/user/example/example>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/example/example/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess example python-path=/home/user/example python-home=/home/user/example/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup example

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "Direct IP access" the suggestion below o host header is valid up until someone knows they can manually override host/ip with the local hosts file and send the host header to any IP of their choosing. One way would be shield them behind a proxy like nginx or haproxy. Firewall the interfaces to only allow that traffic from the proxy, or use separate interfaces all together to tie proxy and web servers together. People can get to hosts through one IP only that way.

IS this the correct end goal, or am I misinterpreting that?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to require that the client sends a `Host` header:

```
Require expr %{HTTP_HOST} .
```

Probably a better way is to define virtual hosts for all of the hostnames you want to support, but have the first virtual host, which is the default if none of the other ones match, deny connections:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  Require all denied
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName admin.example.com
</Virtualhost>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

referring to `httpd-2.4+` version, adding below lines will work:

```
  <If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'example.com' && %{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com' && %{HTTP_HOST} != 'test1.example.com' && %{HTTP_HOST} != 'test2.example.com' && %{HTTP_HOST} != 'test3.example.com' && %{HTTP_HOST} != 'test4.example.com' && %{HTTP_HOST} != 'test5.example.com'" >
    Redirect 403 /
    UseCanonicalName Off
  </If>
```